# getcontentresolver () is undefined for the type

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I try to get all contact names and number and i'm trying to use `getContentResolver` but i am getting

> the method get content resolver () is undefined for the type

this error.

How can i fix it ?

Here is the code below :

```
public class ContactManager  {

public ArrayList<Product> getContactNumber() {
    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
            null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        String name = phones
                .getString(phones
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String phoneNumber = phones
                .getString(phones
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
    }
    phones.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is `Context`, pass context of your `Activity` which use your `Class` in it's Constructor :

```
Context context;
public ContactManager (Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

then use

> context.getContentResolver()

absolutely perfect the use of context here.

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply use this:

```
 public class ContactManager  {

  public ArrayList<Product> getContactNumber(Context mContext) {
    Cursor phones = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
        null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
    String name = phones
            .getString(phones
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
    String phoneNumber = phones
            .getString(phones
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
}
   phones.close();}}
```