# Using getContentResolver() within DatabaseHelper class

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

**EDIT AT BOTTOM OF POST**

I'm just starting to use `ContentProviders` in my project so forgive the newbie question. Also in case it's relevant I'm using [this](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/11/android-database-content-provider.html) tutorial as reference.

From what I understand I have to report to my `ContentProvider` of any CRUD operations for it to notify any other area in my project of those changes. But my problem is my CRUD operations are all inside my `DatabaseHelper.class` along with my queries and such. So when I try to use `getContentResolver().CRUD(uri, cv, null, null)` I get a mark over `getContentResolver()` with the message `Cannot resolve method`.

Now when I looked up on `ContentResolver` I found that I can only use it within a class that `extends Activity`, but since all my CRUD operations are held within my `DatabaseHelper.class` which `extends SQLiteOpenHelper` not `Activity`.

I'm not sure how to get around this if anyone can guide a beginner accordingly that would be greatly appreciated. Below are my CRUD operations in `DatabaseHelper`, if anything else is needed just ask:

**Add**

```
    void AddAccount(Account acc) {


    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();


    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(colName, acc.getName());
    cv.put(colComp, acc.getComp());
    cv.put(colAmount, acc.getAmt());
    cv.put(colPurpose, acc.getPurpose());
    cv.put(colTerms, acc.getTerms());
    cv.put(colPeriod, acc.getPeriod());
    cv.put(colBalance, acc.getAmt());
    cv.put(colStatus, acc.getStatus());
    cv.put(colDate, acc.getDate());
    cv.put(colEditDate, acc.getEditDate());

    db.insert(ACCOUNTS, colName, cv);
    getContentResolver().insert(ContentProviderDB.CONTENT_URI, cv);
    db.close();
}
```

**Update**

```
    public int UpdateAcc(Account acc) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(colName, acc.getName());
    cv.put(colComp, acc.getComp());
    cv.put(colAmount, acc.getAmt());
    cv.put(colPurpose, acc.getPurpose());
    cv.put(colTerms, acc.getTerms());
    cv.put(colPeriod, acc.getPeriod());
    cv.put(colEditDate, acc.getEditDate());
    cv.put(colStatus, acc.getStatus());
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(ContentProviderDB.CONTENT_URI + "/" + acc.getID());
    getContentResolver().update(uri, cv, null, null);
    return db.update(ACCOUNTS, cv, colID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(acc.getID())});

}
```

**Delete**

```
    public void DeleteAcc(Account acc) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(ACCOUNTS, colID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(acc.getID())});
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(ContentProviderDB.CONTENT_URI + "/" + acc.getID());
    getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
    db.close();

}
```

**EDIT**

I'm trying something out but I don't know if it will work properly since I don't even know if I'm implementing `ContentProvider` properly. So far it removes the errors but can someone confirm if this is a valid solution for my problem?

I originally call the CRUD methods this way: `dbHelper.AddAccount(acc);` but since I need to pass the context of the activity to allow `getContextResolver()` I modified the call to `dbHelper.AddAccount(getApplicationContext(),acc);` and also adjusted the CRUD operations like so

```
    void AddAccount(Context con, Account acc) {


    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();


    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(colName, acc.getName());
    cv.put(colComp, acc.getComp());
    cv.put(colAmount, acc.getAmt());
    cv.put(colPurpose, acc.getPurpose());
    cv.put(colTerms, acc.getTerms());
    cv.put(colPeriod, acc.getPeriod());
    cv.put(colBalance, acc.getAmt());
    cv.put(colStatus, acc.getStatus());
    cv.put(colDate, acc.getDate());
    cv.put(colEditDate, acc.getEditDate());

    db.insert(ACCOUNTS, colName, cv);
    con.getContentResolver().insert(ContentProviderDB.CONTENT_URI, cv);
    db.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getContentResolver()` is method of class `android.content.Context`, so to call it you definitely need an instance of `Context` ( `Activity` or `Service` for example).

You need to pass `Context` of your class. See below link for further detail

[getcontentresolver () is undefined for the type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182426/getcontentresolver-is-undefined-for-the-type)

Comment: I added an EDIT to my post in regards to passing the context of the activity. Can you by any chance confirm if it's a valid solution?

Comment: Try passing YourActivityName.this in Context parameter.